# How to write some information to end of file before any word?

Tags: php, xml, file

I want write information to end of file before last word. How can I do that?
My code:

```
$fp=fopen("sitemap.xml","a");
fwrite($fp, "\r\n" . "My information");
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the last word?
Seek to the end of the file, backtrack until first whitespace character, save all data from current point to EOF, insert your data, insert saved data

## Update #1

Change the mode of your fopen to `r+` as `a` will always write @ EOF